# No value return in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this query below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_myTest
    @emp_ids nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        Count(*) 
    FROM
        emp_service t
    INNER JOIN 
        t_emp e ON t.emp_id = e.emp_id
    WHERE 
        (t.emp_id IN (Select * FROM dbo.Split(@emp_ids, ',')) OR @emp_ids = '' OR @emp_ids IS NULL)
        AND t.status IN ('A', 'R', 'S')
    GROUP BY 
        t.emp_id
END
```

In the stored procedure above, I have two tables: Employee Service (`emp_service`) and Employee table `t_emp`.

What I am trying to do here is to find out the employee service's status. Let's say 'A' is active, 'R' is removed, and 'S' is suspended. In this query, I want to find the number of services that is corresponding to the emp_id.

For example: my emp_id is '15000' and I have three services and their status is 'A', 'S', 'A'. In this case, the expected result should return '3' (I have run it using only the select statement and it return the correct result)

```
Declare @emp_ids nvarchar(max)

Set @emp_id = '15000'

Select Count(*) 
    From emp_service t
    INNER JOIN t_emp e
    ON t.emp_id = e.emp_id
    WHERE 
        (t.emp_id IN (Select * FROM dbo.Split(@emp_ids, ',')) OR @emp_ids = '' OR @emp_ids IS NULL)
        and t.status in ('A', 'R', 'S')
        GROUP BY t.emp_id
```

This query return '3' which is the correct result.

However, when I am trying to execute the stored procedure, it return '0'. I am not sure why it come out different result. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: it may occur because of the value is not setting correct for the stored procedure ,
that you can check through edit the query inside the stored procedure with the hard code value and try what the result came

Comment: i m not sure about this but i think it's ALTER PROCEDURE sp_myTest
   ( @emp_ids nvarchar(max) )

AS

Comment: @Drag, Show `exec` code.

Comment: Possibly your parameter in the `exec` statement is not in the correct format. Make sure you call the procedure with a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` parameter where the values are split with a comma.

Comment: Do not use the `sp_` prefix! This is reserved an might cause problems later...

Comment: How do you call the procedure? I guess you are mixing up procedures and functions. In SQL Server, procedures and functions are treated more differently than in other languages like C#/Java.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is like trying to cut a tree with a knife. Possible, but wrong tool though...

Much better was a function. A Stored Procedure is meant to *do* something and there *can* be a result. Functions are meant to *deliver a typed result* and you are not even allowed to *do* something in there.

Althoug there are many examples with SPs doing nothing else than to read data this is a bad habit to get rid of.

Try it like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyTest
(
    @emp_ids nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
        Select Count(*) 
        From emp_service t
        INNER JOIN t_emp e
        ON t.emp_id = e.emp_id
        WHERE 
            (t.emp_id IN (Select * FROM dbo.Split(@emp_ids, ',')) OR @emp_ids = '' OR @emp_ids IS NULL)
            and t.status in ('A', 'R', 'S')
            GROUP BY t.emp_id
    );
END
```

And you call this like

```
SELECT dbo.MyTest('SomeEmpId');
```

Comment: This does not answer the question raised which is"why does it come out a different result?"

Comment: @corky_bantam OK... If you ask an expert (here: a wood cutter), why the tree is still standing, allthough you're working with your knife for hours I hope he will tell you to use a saw... A *real* answer is not possible without the actual execution call. This was asked by SQLGeorge but the OP did not yet answer...